# ASK demodulator not working as expected

Tags: transistors, capacitor, resistors, inductor, demodulation

I have implemented an ASK modulator and demodulator pair. The modulator works fine, but the demodulator is giving a vague output. Below is the image of the whole circuit and the simulation output.

[image]

In the below output, blue is the carrier of 27 MHz, red is the digital wave of 150 KHz, green is the ASK output and yellow is the de modulator output.

[image: tra]

I am not much of an electronics guy, so not good in tuning the circuit. Please help me achieve the desired output so that the yellow wave resembles the red digital wave.

EDIT 1 -

After trying many combinations of R11 and C2 values, finally i got one that is sending considerable voltage into demodulator. The output is still a straight line but its non zero this time.

Here blue is the volatage after the R11 and yellow is output from demodulator. 
[image]

Comment: explain how the circuit works.

Comment: Hi. I don't have much of domain knowledge. I just replicated the circuit from http://www.pyroelectro.com/projects/pyro_rf_receiver_27mhz/index.html. They have also provided explanation (which ofcourse is out of my scope)

Comment: Great gravy.  I said a "largish" resistor.  I didn't say "replace the wire with a nearly open circuit."  Reduce it to something reasonable (several kohm) and make C2 larger (nanofarad range.)  Do you know what a high pass filter is?  Look it up.  C2 is just too danged small if you have any kind of load on it

Comment: @JRE i replaced with nano cap and 10k res, but the yellow output is still similar

Comment: You have a simulator there in front of you, and a possible problem with C2 and R11.  The demodulator will need **some** current to operate - 10k may be way too much.  Lower it.  It costs nothing to run the simulator.  If you lower R11, and the "transmit" signal wimps out, increase C2.    Prove to yourself that the demodulator doesn't work at all:  C2 at like 100nF, and R11 just a piece of wire or a less than 100 ohm resistor.  If it still just gives a bump, well now you know the demodulator is really not doing much.

Comment: A 2n2222 may not be fast enough for 27 MHz

Comment: Probe the waveform node by node from input to output of demodulator and try to see where it does not behave as you expect.  You may spot a point where the signal is swamped or not amplified due to missing bias or something else.

Comment: Your transistor Q3 has no DC bias and will not respond to a small input signal.

Comment: "considerable" is not a value, and your second graph has no scale.  What is the peak-to-peak voltage at junction of C4 and R7?

Comment: @MikeP Actually the website i have referred to, he has made a PCB as well with real components and is getting the correct output. He also recorded a video showing that.